# How can I export view data in hive?

Tags: csv, hive, hiveql

I have created 4 tables (a,b,c,d) in hive and created a view (x) on top of that tables by joining them.

-- How can i export the x underlying csv data from hdfs to local ?

-- How can i keep this csv in hdfs

for tables , we can do **show create table a**;

this will show the location of the hdfs where the underlying csv is stored.

hadoop fs get --from source_path_and_file --to dest_path_and_file

similarly how can i get the csv data from view into my local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export view data to the CSV using this:

```
insert overwrite local directory '/user/home/dir' row format delimited fields terminated by ',' select * from view;
```

Concatenate files in the local directory if you need single file using `cat` :

```
cat /user/home/dir/* > view.csv
```

Alternatively if the dataset is small, you can add `order by` in the query, this will trigger single reducer and produce single ordered file. This will perform slow if the dataset is big.

Answer (score 0):

1) to write your results in file you can use `INSERT OVERWRITE` as below:

```
insert overwrite local directory '/tmp/output'
row format delimited
fields terminated by '|'
select * from <view>;
```

2) If you want to write a file into HDFS then use above `insert overwrite` statement with `local`

3) No separate HDFS location for views.

**View** are purely logical construct from the table and there is no separate underlying storage created for them in HDFS.

**Views** are being used when you want to store intermediate results and query them directly instead of writing complex query on that table again and again. It's like we use `with blocks` in our query.