# Improve performance while redirecting output using Beeline

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, beeline

We are running a query on production and collecting results in a flat file
This file is then mailed to the end user. This file contains millions of records.

Our query completes in 10 mins or so, but redirecting the output to the flat file takes 30-40 mins

Is there any way we can speed up the redirection?

Comment: Create file in the HDFS using `insert overwrite table or directory` and get file to the local using `hadoop fs -get /hdfs/source/path /localfs/destination/path`

Comment: @leftjoin: is it worth expanding on that remark in an answer proper?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I export view data in hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54768501/how-can-i-export-view-data-in-hive)